# IIS 7.5 - how to get?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

My servers are currently running IIS 7 (windows 2008).  Is there any way to get IIS 7.5 without upgrading to 2008 R2?

The reason I ask is that they are 32 bit servers and there is no upgrade path from 32 bit 2008 to 2008 R2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. You basically should never have installed 2008 32 bit for an IIS server. Microsoft made it pretty clear back then that this would be a dead end. ;)

Comment: I had to.  The machine was hosting an app that required the 32bit version of windows server.

Comment: Actually no - the 64 bit version can perfectly run 32 bit applications, except drivers.

Comment: I know this is old, but I thought I'd make it a bit more clear about the app.  The app in question was TFS 2010.  It  requires 32bit windows and doesn't support installation on 64 bit windows.  There are apparently ways to get around this, but those involved way more work than we were interested in.